# unusual lecture in 空かに見えやしないか?

Tags: grammar, translation

> ぼくらとちがったやつからみてもやっぱりこんな地層に見えるかどうか、あるいは風か水やがらんとした**空かに**見えやしないかということなのだ。わかったかい

1) 空か is some kind of strange lecture for 空 or it just plain 空 plus か

2) How do you take the second part of the quote, after, あるいは, 見えやしないか confuses me because it is a negative question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't quite understand what the speaker is saying overall, but the structure is clear.

> ［風］か［水やがらんとした空］か

So it's 空 followed by か.

見えやしないか is a colloquial pronunciation of 見えはしないか ([What is this や in 大きすぎや?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5875/7810)), so the や has nothing to do with the enumerating particle. 見えはしないか is basically the same as 見えないか "Doesn't one see...?" except that the whole phrase before 見え is topicalized. It indicates that the speaker's main concern is on that part, in this case, like "Shouldn't one see...?" or "Does perhaps one see...?".

- ［ぼくらと……しないか］ということなのだ
  *The question (*‌or *my point) is [......]*

  - ぼくらとちがったやつからみても［やっぱり…］あるいは［風か水や…］
    *from the eye of something different from us, [...] (or) otherwise [...]*

    - やっぱりこんな地層に見えるかどうか
      *whether it looks like (to them) the same strata or not*
    - ［風か水や……とした空］に見えやしないか
      *whether it should look like [...] or not*

      - ［風］か［水やがらんとした空］か
        *[wind] or [(something like) water or empty sky]*